# Serve an external Webdav resources form IIS

Tags: iis-7, webdav

I can connect to an external webdav resource after installing from Windows Server after installing the windows desktop experience witch in turn installs the webdav client.

- I see the webdav folders and I can access them manually from the server Explorer after having mapped them with "Map Network Drive"

BUT

- I can't serve them via IIS virtual folders - Is there a way to do it?
- I can't connect to them via a normal webdav client like Cyberduck

If I arrive to connect them with a webdav client I was thinking to access them with a .Net component and serve them (readonly) from IIS.

Is this the correct approach and why I arrive to connect only with Explorer and not with other clients?